# Extracting a string starting with # or @ php

Tags: php, arrays, string, hash, extract

```
function extractConnect($str,$connect_type){

    $connect_array = array();
    $connect_counter = 0;
    $str = trim($str).' ';

    for($i =0; $i<strlen($str);$i++) {
        $chr  = $str[$i];
        if($chr==$connect_type){          //$connect_type  = '#' or '@' etc
            $connectword = getConnect($i,$str);
            $connect_array[$connect_counter] = $connectword;
            $connect_counter++;
        }
    }
    if(!empty($connect_array)){
        return $connect_array;
    }
}
function getConnect($tag_index,$str){       
    $str = trim($str).' ';
    for($j = $tag_index; $j<strlen($str);$j++) {
        $chr  = $str[$j];
        if($chr==' '){
            $hashword = substr($str,$tag_index+1,$j-$tag_index);                
            return trim($hashword); 
        }

    }
}
$at = extractConnect("#stackoverflow is great. @google.com is the best search engine","@");
$hash = extractConnect("#stackoverflow is great. @google.com is the best search engine","#");

print_r($at);
print_r($hash);
```

What this method does is it extracts `#` or `@` from a string and return an array of those words.
e.g input `#stackoverflow is great. @google.com is the best search engine` and outputs this

```
Array ( [0] => google.com ) Array ( [0] => stackoverflow )
```

But it seems like this method is to slow is there any alternative ?

Comment: U could make an array with all those characters(# or @..) and then you check if in_array($characters, $yourArrayWithData); Your method seems !!!way to complicated!!!. This would be an idea, dont have time to write an answer now.

Comment: but @Xatenev i dont have any specific characters! there can be any ... What i have is only `@` and `#`

Comment: @HackerManiac: What kind of characters could it be?

Comment: Yea so you simply check in_array($characters,$yourstringwithdata) and afterwards, you take the word when its in there

Comment: @Xatenev #xantev #hackermanic #stackoverflow etc anything !

Comment: Because at the moment, you do the search for EVERY string, including substr check and strlen check and i dont even know what else.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php

function extractConnect($strSource, $tags) {
    $matches = array();
    $tags = str_split($tags);
    $strSource = explode(' ', $strSource);
    array_walk_recursive($strSource, function(&$item) {
        $item = trim($item);
    });
    foreach ($strSource as $strPart) {
        if (in_array($strPart[0], $tags)) {
            $matches[$strPart[0]][] = substr($strPart, 1);
        }
    }
    return $matches;
}

var_dump(extractConnect(
    "#stackoverflow is great. #twitter is good. @google.com is the best search engine",
    "#@"
));
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: I want a seperate array for `#` and `@` but wanna run the function only once!!

Comment: latheesan it worked but i accepted @AmalMurali 's answer coz it was very short and understandable!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to achieve this:

```
/<char>(\S+)\b/i
```

Explanation:

- `/` - starting delimiter
- `<char>` - the character you're searching for (passed as a function argument)
- `(\S+)` - any non-whitespace character, one or more times
- `\b` - [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `i` - [case insensitivity modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)
- `/` - ending delimiter

Function:

```
function extractConnect($string, $char) {
    $search = preg_quote($char, '/');
    if (preg_match('/'.$search.'(\S+)\b/i', $string, $matches)) {
        return [$matches[1]]; // Return an array containing the match
    }
    return false;
}
```

With your strings, this would produce the following output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "google.com"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "stackoverflow"
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/154209)

Answer (score -2):

This seemed to work for me. Provide it with the symbol you want.

```
function get_stuff($str) {
    $result = array();
    $words = explode(' ', $str);
    $symbols = array('@', '#');
    foreach($words as $word) {
        if (in_array($word[0], $symbols)) {
            $result[$word[0]][] = substr($word, 1);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$str = '#stackoverflow is great. @google.com is the best search engine';

print_r(get_stuff($str));
```

This outputs `Array ( [#] => Array ( [0] => stackoverflow ) [@] => Array ( [0] => google.com ) )`

Comment: i want # and @ seperately ! @mts7

Comment: wanna run function once but return 2 arrays !! `return array("@"=>$hashed_words,"#"=>$at_words)`

Comment: @HackerManiac see my answer, I think I've done what you're looking for.

Comment: @HackerManiac updated to give you one array with the other 2 arrays inside.